# python reverse a binary pattern within an integer

Tags: python, performance, binary

Is there a fast possibility to reverse a binary number in python?

Example: I have the number 11 in binary 0000000000001011 with 16 Bits. Now I'm searching for a **fast** function f, which returns 1101000000000000 (decimal 53248). Lookup tables are no solutions since i want it to scale to 32Bit numbers. Thank you for your effort.

Edit:

**Performances**. I tested the code for all 2^16 pattern several times.

- winner are the partially look up tables: 30ms
- 2nd `int(format(num, '016b')[::-1], 2)` from the comments: 56ms
- 3rd `x = ((x & 0x00FF) << 8) | (x >> 8)`: 65ms
- I did not expect my approach to be so horribly slow but it is.
  approx. 320ms. Small improvement by using + instead of | 300ms
- `bytes(str(num).encode('utf-8'))` fought for the 2nd place but somehow
  the code did not provide valid answers. Most likely because I made a
  mistake by transforming them into an integer again.

thank you very much for your input. I was quite surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be faster using small 8-bit lookup table:

```
num = 11
# One time creation of 8bit lookup
rev = [int(format(b, '08b')[::-1], base=2) for b in range(256)]

# Run for each number to be flipped.
lower_rev = rev[num & 0xFF] << 8
upper_rev = rev[(num & 0xFF00) >> 8]
flipped = lower_rev + upper_rev
```

Comment: thank you, I guess partly using luts is probably the fastest solution. I will run a test and post my results

Answer (score 1):

My current approach is to access the bits via bit shifting and mask and to shift them in the mirror number until they reach their destination. Still I have the feeling that there is room for improvement.

```
num = 11
print(format(num, '016b'))

right = num
left = 0
for i in range(16):
  tmp = right & 1
  left = (left << 1 ) | tmp
  right = right >> 1


print(format(left, '016b'))
```

Comment: What about `print(int(format(num, '016b')[::-1], 2))`.

Comment: @Matthias IMO `int->str->int` does not satisfies the requirement for "fast function"..

Comment: @JanStránský So you have something faster?

Comment: @JanStránský This was the first idea I had (still waiting for other solutions to come up). If you want a really fast function then you could write a library in C. Still benchmarking would be needed to see which solution is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use slicing to get what you are looking for:

```
b=bytes('0000000000001011'.encode('utf-8'))
>>> b
b'0000000000001011'
>>> b[::-1]
b'1101000000000000'
```

Comment: Why would you encode to bytes instead of just reversing the string?

Comment: @khelwood the original question didn’t show the type. I cast as bytes on the assumption (possibly incorrectly) that the data is in bytes. The slicing would work equally as well on a string

Answer (score 1):

There's this, but in Python it seems slower than Matthias' proposed `int`->`str`->`int` solution.

```
x = ((x & 0x5555) << 1) | ((x & 0xAAAA) >> 1)
x = ((x & 0x3333) << 2) | ((x & 0xCCCC) >> 2)
x = ((x & 0x0F0F) << 4) | ((x & 0xF0F0) >> 4)
x = ((x & 0x00FF) << 8) | (x >> 8)
```